# sql , two USING clauses in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql

im just doing some sql exercises on w3 and wondering about the following statement

```
SELECT a.ord_no, a.purch_amt, b.cust_name, c.name,
FROM orders a 
INNER JOIN customer b USING (customer_id) 
INNER JOIN salesman c USING (salesman_id)
```

edit: i posted wrong testing results , statement doesnt work for reasons explained by answer from ScaisEdge.

Comment: It's probably because of column names conflicts, but it's hard to tell withouth the tables' structure

Comment: Probably because with more than two tables involved it's impossible to figure our which ones you mean.

Comment: Are all column names unique across both tables? If not, you may have to use `ON` to do the join

Comment: Make sure `customer_id` and `salesman_id` exist in `orders` table.  Can you include the queries that work? That might give some insight on the issue you're having.

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-joins-exercises.php#SQLEDITOR its exercise 6. I mean if there would be any conflict then at least one swap of the clause shouldnt work or? but it doesnt matter which of the two  i swap out,  it will work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to your code

```
FROM orders a 
INNER JOIN customer b USING (customer_id) 
INNER JOIN salesman c USING (salesman_id)
```

seems that the `using` clause  is ambigous  when you use more then 2 tables 
In your case the second  using is  for customer or orders  .. ??

The sql engine can't define the correct one  so you must use explicit on clause  for avoid using ambiguity

Comment: yeah thats what i thought, but i find it interesting that if i swap any of them, he would suddenly "know"  how to correctly interpret the other USING clause. (as said no matter which i swap out)

Comment: swapping the inner join clause is non sense  in sql  .. there in not a first table and a second  table  .. the swap don't resolve ambiguity in sql  .. sql is not a  procedural  ..is a declarative language  .. if you use more then two table you must use explicit join on clause  .. or where condition but not using clause

Comment: ok i just tested it again, it only works when the first statement uses the USING clause, but the second has to be an ON clause, which i think makes perfect sense and is exactly what u said. Somehow in my first test i assumed it worked  the other way around also (first ON then USING in the second statement), which it doesnt , thats what got me really confused .

Comment: I always avoid the USING clause for this reason  ... can easly create  confusion  .. so i  always use explict join and well formed  on clause